# Comparing monthly data within a single query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have data in a table. I am trying to use the query, or similar, function in sheets to then show a comparison month over month as well as trailing 3 month reveue.

See [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/116adU_Vs5wn12kq3bzwRIM8LVUyYc3ZV6SGpLEV1scs/edit#gid=1432283259) - the data tab is the input, the desired tab is the desired output, but I was hoping to put it all within the single query formula.

If I am unable to put in a single query formula, I'd love any input on how to convert the sumifs formulae to an array formula.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Simplified sheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rnLmRAUdeI1K5gYNJ4rGgjEs92O28HWCqAiOpAfbXe8/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

you can do `SUMIFS` in array like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(FILTER(Data!A2:A, Data!A2:A<>"")&
 EOMONTH(FILTER(Data!B2:B, Data!B2:B<>""), -1), 
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, 0), 0))
```

[image]

Comment: This formula is more straightforward but isnt getting the answer I expected?

Comment: @conor are you sure? as you can see formula in I column generates exactly what you request in D column

Comment: Your screenshot shows 0, $264.8, 12, 13.6 in Column I in the screenshot you shared for this formula? =ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(FILTER(Data!A2:A, Data!A2:A<>"")&
 EOMONTH(FILTER(Data!B2:B, Data!B2:B<>""), -1), 
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, 
 "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, 0), 0))

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Data!A:C, IFERROR(
 {"Prior month Revenue", "MoM Change", "% MoM", "Trailing 3 month revenue"; 
 IFNA(VLOOKUP(Data!A2:A&EOMONTH(Data!B2:B, -1),
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, ), 0),  Data!C2:C-IFNA(VLOOKUP(Data!A2:A&EOMONTH(Data!B2:B, -1), 
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, ), 0), (Data!C2:C-IFNA(VLOOKUP(Data!A2:A&EOMONTH(Data!B2:B, -1), 
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, ), 0))/          (IFNA(VLOOKUP(Data!A2:A&EOMONTH(Data!B2:B, -1), 
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, ), 0)), Data!C2:C+IFNA(VLOOKUP(Data!A2:A&EOMONTH(Data!B2:B, -1), 
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, ), 0)+            IFNA(VLOOKUP(Data!A2:A&EOMONTH(Data!B2:B, -2), 
 QUERY({Data!A2:A&Data!B2:B, Data!C2:C}, "select Col1,sum(Col2) group by Col1"), 2, ), 0)}, 0)}, "where Col1 is not null", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain to me how this logic works?

Comment: @conor it's all-in-one formula based on the previous answer generating exactly what you requested. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/116adU_Vs5wn12kq3bzwRIM8LVUyYc3ZV6SGpLEV1scs/edit#gid=1403000722